# Trouble with an USB modem on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, modem, usb-modem

I need to connect my laptop using an USB modem. I have tried the modem on a
Windows 7 machine and it works fine, so I regard my trouble is software
related. But I use Ubuntu 11.10 on daily basis, so I need to make it work on
Ubuntu 11.10.

Before connecting the modem I clear up the messages with:

```
sudo dmesg -c
```

Then I connect the modem, wait for a moment and execute `dmesg` one more
time. This is the result:

```
[91378.255708] usb 3-1: new high speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[91378.272193] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.272318] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.272410] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.274833] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.274953] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.412746] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91378.412854] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[91379.410604] usb 3-1: usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd mtp-probe rqt 128 rq 6 len 1024 ret -110
```

The modem is actually detected::

```
$ lsusb | grep -i modem
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 047e:2892 Agere Systems, Inc. (Lucent) Systems Soft Modem
```

But `gnome-ppp` won't see it.

### Update

Following the comment from Scott, I think I should rephrase my question to this:

have anyone figure out the right switchmode command for the Agere modem 047e:2892?

Any ideas?

Best regards,

Manuel.

Comment: It's not an answer, but it's relevant: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.linmodem/30106 ... essentially if you want support, buy supported hardware.

Comment: how about posting the output of sudo lshw -C network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More and more USB devices have their MS Windows drivers onboard; when plugged in for the first time they act like a flash storage and start installing the driver from there. After installation (and on every consecutive plugging) the driver switches the mode internally, the storage device vanishes (in most cases), and a new device (like an USB modem) shows up. Modem maker "Option" calls that feature "ZeroCD (TM)" since it eliminates the need for shipping a separate driver carrier.

I would imagine that Ubuntu is detecting your modem as a usb flash drive instead of a modem and that's why gnome-ppp is not detecting it.  You need to set the mode manually in order for it to be detected as a modem.  I have provided a link to download and explain in further detail on how to go about performing this operatioin.

http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

Comment: I will read the link and report back later. Thanks, and best regards, Manuel.

Comment: The link provided, though quite informative, haven't helped me. The basic problem is that I have not been able to find the correct switch command for my modem. Furthermore, no Agere modem is currently supported directly by usb_modemswitch. At least, there are no 047E on my /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules files.